# "beauty of Paris" auf Deutsch

Tags: genitive

Are these two expressions both possible translations of "beauty of Paris"?

1) Schönheit von Paris

2) Paris Schönheit

?

Is there even more ways how to translate "beauty of Paris" into German?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Each (unobvious) way of translating something depends on the particular context. The first item is the obvious translation of *beauty of Paris*.

Comment: The sentence 2) is an effort to use the genitive without the usage of "das".

Answer (score 2):

> (Die) Schönheit von Paris

is the best option.

> - Paris' Schönheit
> - Die Schönheit Paris'

are also possible from my point of view (see [Wiktionary entry for *Paris’*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%99)), but they are harder to read and sound odd when spoken because the genitive suffix gets lost (*Die Schönheit Berlin**s***, however, would be unambigous and sounds perfect).

Comment: For "beauty of Prague" the genitive form would be "Prags Schönheit". Isn't the order reversed for your sentence about Berlin? "Berlins Schönheit"?

Comment: @AlexanderParker just like *Die Schönheit Paris'* and *Paris' Schönheit* (see my answer), you can say *Die Schönheit Prags* or *Prags Schönheit*. I would prefer *Die Schönheit Prags*, to me it sounds more common and stylistically more appropriate in a text about beauty